# ActiveMQ Failed to unregister MBean

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic, jmx

I've got some pretty basic usage of JMS (using Spring's JMSTemplate to send the message).  I recently just upgraded from ActiveMQ 5.5.1 to ActiveMQ 5.8.0 and I see continual references to failures with MBeans unregistering

e.g.

```
{ActiveMQ VMTransport: vm://vmBroker#27-8} WARNING
org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagedRegionBroker Failed to unregister MBean:
org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=vmBroker,destinationType=Queue,
destinationName=gcm-messages,endpoint=Producer,
clientId=ID_ip-20-64-831-81-36881-1383335667547-4_14,producerId=ID_ip-10-84-234-30-36881-1383335667547-5_14_15627_1
```

In looking at JMX it is true that there's an explosion of activemq mbeans.

Is anyone aware of an issue with ActiveMQ that might cause this?  Or how it might be fixed?

Comment: Try the latest release v5.9.0 it's got a lot of fixes

Comment: what container, JDK, and OS do you use? Do you run standalone broker or embedded in some container?

Comment: Java 6 running in Resin 4.  It occurs on both Mac OSX and Linux.